# why is this question closed as not clear what you are asking

Tags: discussion

i am referring to this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16412/fadak-fatima-and-abu-baker) where in user fatemah clearly asks what is the reason for dispute between abu-bakr and fatema (s.a)

but even though the question is closed, saying unclear as what you are asking

Answer (score 3):

The question is closed simply because the question has been answered in the question body itself.

> I can't tell what you're actually
>   asking here that isn't already
>   answered by your own question.
>   Please spend some more time
>   focusing it to clarify exactly what
>   you're looking for in an answer. –
>   goldPseudo ♦ Jul 22 at 15:41

Comment: i think she wants a sunni rivaaya for that issue,

Comment: And that's the thing. A question where one has to guess what is being asked is definitely unclear.